# Dual booting 2 windows 10 with 1 encrypted

Tags: windows-10, boot, encryption

I would like a dual boot system with 2 windows 10 systems installed.

I have one 256GB SSD.

One of the OS has to be encrypted.But the other one will nut be encrypted at all.
When I boot the conputer,I want to start the unencrypted OS directly,and not having to enter any password.

When I want to boot the second OS,I go to Settings,and restart the computer to boot the second OS.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why does one have to be encrypted? Did you try to install them both and set them up in such a fashion? What kind of encryption are you going to use? You likely won't be able to use whole drive encryption. Why does one have to be unencrypted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to boot the encrypted OS only after loading the unencrypted one as you described, your best bet is a Virtual Machine.  Something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) will do the trick.  What this will do is load the second OS as a file on a logical drive, but you can encrypt the whole file as well as having the OS encrypt itself when you set it up.  This is infinitely more secure than what you're proposing, as running unsecured and secured in parallel exposes your secured OS to risks it need not have. You can also back up the file, or even expand it to the full hardware on the machine.

This also means that if you're using the encrypted version for an important project, deep web access, or something else you don't want prying code to crawl around in, you can delete the machine entirely and the only thing a data recovery tool or DR-capable malware will find is a 128-bit encrypted blob with a 128-bit encrypted blob inside of it. Nothing beats a DoD-approved zero-write erasure on an HDD, but I don't think anyone wants to spend a lifetime trying to decrypt your encrypted VM file and then another on its encrypted volumes.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a VM? My computer isn't that fast,and a VM might run really slowly.